# laravel broadcasting in admin guard

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, broadcast

In my laravel website , we have two guard `admin` and `customer` this guard's tables is ->`customer table` and `admin table`.

I would like to send the notification from a `customer` to an `admin` via the `laravel broadcasting`
this is my codes in the .js file into the **admin guard**

server.js files:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({

   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
}); 

* i have a admin by id=2 *

Echo.private('App.Models.Admin.2')
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });
```

and into the **customer guard**:

```
\Notification::send(Admin::find(2) , new SimpleAlert('hey bro'));
```

SimpleAlert.php:

```
public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'message' => $this->message,
        'type' => 'broadcast'
    ]);
}
```

so, i start the laravel-echo-server and open two google chrome tab, one for `admin guard` and another for `customer guard`and logged into the both guard.
No error into console. No error into `customer sending notification`, but `admin not receive the notification.

**Problem:**
laravel-echo-server showing this when i into the `admin guard`

> Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403

help me please.

Comment: you need to authorize `App.Models.Admin.2` in `channels` routes check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add the authorization in `routes/channels.php`. Try this

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Admin.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return $user->id === $userId;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer did not work for me. The reason it doesn't work is because you are comparing the intended id ($userId) to an authenticated user on the user table and not the admin table. To send a message on a private channel to an admin person this worked for me:

in routes/channels.php.

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Admin.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id === $userId;
});
```